# Auto-saving an Excel file opened from a template file

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro-enabled Excel file (.xlsm) and I would like to save all files opened with the template to a certain location with the date in the file name immediately after double-clicking the template.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " Timesheet"
End Sub
```

I'd like it to save with the last day of the work week.

The file name should be "Week Ending in mm-dd-yyyy).
I have a formula in my workbook that does this, but I'm not sure if this is the same as VBA code.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=7,TODAY()-1,IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=6,TODAY(),TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with how you are currently implementing your code.

> 1. Opening your template file will autosave it so editing the original becomes more difficult
> 2. You can't access the templates path if you open it as a normal file

Hopefully the following will help implement the template although you will need to hardcode the desired path in the code

> In 'ThisWorkbook'

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call SaveFromTemplate
End Sub
```

> In a module

```
Function SaveFromTemplate()
    Dim Path As String: Path = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    If Not Right(Path, Len(Path) - InStrRev(Path, ".")) = "xltm" Then
        Path = "C:\Edit this path\"
        ' Friday = 6
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Path & Format(WeekdayDate(Date, 6), "yyyy-mm-dd") & " Timesheet"
    End If
End Function

Function WeekdayDate(DateVal As Date, DayInWeek As Long) As Date
    DayInWeek = DayInWeek Mod 7
    Dim DayOffset As Long: DayOffset = DayInWeek - Weekday(DateVal) + IIf(DayInWeek - Weekday(DateVal) < 0, 7, 0)
    WeekdayDate = DateAdd("d", DayOffset, DateVal)
End Function
```

*** ADDENDUM ***

I hadn't realised you were using a '.xlsm' as your template start. You can relay the template path with this but you will have issues when re-opening the saved '.xlsm'

Modified so it only saves if it's not the 'Timesheet' file

> In 'ThisWorkbook'

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If InStr(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "Timesheet") = 0 Then
        ' Friday = 6
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(WeekdayDate(Date, 6), "yyyy-mm-dd") & " Timesheet"
    End If
End Sub
```